# Is std::array still cache friendly when it stores large objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, caching, cpu-usage, cpu-cache

I understand that std::array is cache friendly , because all the items stored in an std::array are closely packed next to each other. If I iterates through the array, when I try to access one item, CPU would **pre-fetch** the next couple of items.

This is where my confusion comes from: usually XEON cache line is 64 bytes: that's 8  **int64_t** . Imaging I have

```
std::array<BigObject, 100>
```

where each BigObject is of size 512 Bytes. In that case, even all the BigObject items are all packed next to each other, CPU won't be able to do anything smart : it would still have to fetch cache line by line, i.e., 8 lines per BigObject. Therefore,there should not be any cache friendly advantage.

My question is then: for std::array of large objects, is there still the advantage of cache friendliness? If so, why ?

Comment: Remember that modern CPU's have multi-level caches, the third on x86-type CPU's being multi-megabyte. So even if an object won't fit in a single cache-line it could still be in a cache

Comment: What "insight"s are you looking for, exactly? Obviously C++ can't do anything about cpu architecture, or somehow shrink a large object into a fewer number of bytes. This would violate several fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe, unfortunately. So, it's quite unclear what exactly  is being asked here.

Comment: Your CPU will only fetch memory for fields you use. If you only use fields in the first 64 bytes of `BigObject`, one cache line fetch suffices. A Sufficiently Smart Compiler(tm) could insert prefetching instructions if it sees you looping over such an array, but I do not presume this is a simple optimization.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik not sure if you down-voted this question. I have re-phased my post according to your comments.

Comment: Before posting your first question, you should've taken the [tour], visited the [help], and learned [ask] questions on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Cache concerns would seem to be premature optimization.  Not all caches are the same.  Not all caches work as you are guessing.

Comment: std::vector 'packs' it's elements back-to-back in the same layout as an array does, but in dynamic memory.   "Big'er objects" in automatic memory lead to 'SO' !

Comment: @Botje that's exactly where my question comes from : if when I iterate through the array, I only access the first int64_t, then CPU has to fetch again for every item in the array, because the first int64_t is always 512-8=504 bytes away.

Comment: @2785528 I don't think std::vector works as you described. For std::vector, the pointers are packed closely together, but the actually BigObject's are NOT packed one after another.

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector:   "The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets to regular pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an element of an array."  Elements are, in this example, "BigObject", and without concern about what aggregate makes up the BigObject.

Comment: @2785528 I was wrong: the contents are packed next to each other

Comment: "... premature optimization. "  another thought: there seems to be more than 4 hw architectures that run Win 10.  Do you expect all of them to have the same cache implementation?  and cache designs (and memory speeds, and ...) seem to change often (every year? every other year?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to clarify, the speed up of processor caches stems from the fact, that the RAM i.e. memory of a today computer is several times slower than the CPU. So the CPU has some small internal memory, so called cache, which is fast. In order the utilize the small memory best, the CPU usually use the concepts of time and space, meaning things frequently used is kept in cache, and stuff next to the things recently used, their neighbors in the memory, are also loaded into the cache, as its very likely they are needed next.

So as you understood right, things are cached friendly when the are closely in memory. Since `std::array` and `std::vector` are so called **ContiguousContainer**, they are holding their contents next to each other in memory.

So it would be **cache friendly** in deed to hold stuff you used frequently together, i.e. you iterate over in a loop or use after another in such a container.

How ever if you objects are as big as you said, you can do what you want, they are too big to fit into the cache, in a reasonable count. So you could either look what it is you are manipulating so frequently in those objects and are only storing this in the container, or you live with the inevitable slow down. Also you could get a speed up if you define the most important members first in the class or struct you use, since this translates to the layout the members are stored in memory. First things first for class members.

But as all those advise much more importantly: Usually your algorithmic complexity is much more significant to the overall run time of you program. 
For example: Ask you self, does you program do a little work on every big object and goes to the next one, only to do some other little work on every big object later, which is very inefficient, or could you do all work due for an object at once, and only then go forward to the next big object? If not, why are your objects so big? Shouldn't they just contain the stuff needed for the task at hand?
Don't to messy compley things in hope things will get faster. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" is a popular quote is this context. First write your program clear and readable and for correctness. Then run it and measure where it is actually slow. General speculation about cache implementations is not very helpful usually, heuristic like "When in doubt use a vector or array as they are usually the fastest" is good enough.

**Or to better answer you question: `std::array` and `std::vector` are both the best choice for cache friendliness, how ever no container can be cache friendly for big objects, since big objects are cache unfriendly by being big.**